# How to extract attachment from digitally signed pdf?

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, digital-signature

I have some C# code which extracts all attachments from pdf files. It works great, even if it's attached document level or as a file annotation.

However if I digitally sign (and timestamp) these pdf files, the type of the attachment changes from annotation (or fileattachment) to "widget" or something. I'm no pdf expert, and I could not find any method to extract the attachments if the pdf is signed.

Any help appreciated!

[EDIT]

Sample without signature: [samplepdf_notsigned.pdf](http://aboy.hu/samplepdf_notsigned.pdf)

Sample with signature (signed with SetaPDF-Signer API): [samplepdf_signed.pdf](http://aboy.hu/samplepdf_signed.pdf)

Code blocks are the following:

```
/*
 * annotations
 */
iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader reader = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader("samplepdf_annotations.pdf");
for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
{
    iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfArray array = reader.GetPageN(i).GetAsArray(iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfName.ANNOTS);
    if (array == null) continue;
    for (int j = 0; j < array.Size; j++)
    {
        iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfDictionary annot = array.GetAsDict(j);
        if (iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfName.FILEATTACHMENT.Equals(annot.GetAsName(iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfName.SUBTYPE)))
        {
            iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfDictionary fs = annot.GetAsDict(iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfName.FS);
            iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfDictionary refs = fs.GetAsDict(iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfName.EF);
            foreach (iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfName name in refs.Keys)
            {
                // I CAN GET THE ATTACHMENT HERE
                string filename = fs.GetAsString(name).ToString();
                byte[] binary = iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader.GetStreamBytes((iTextSharp.text.pdf.PRStream)refs.GetAsStream(name));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfDictionary fs = annot.GetAsDict(iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfName.FS);
            iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfDictionary refs = fs.GetAsDict(iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfName.EF);
            foreach (iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfName name in refs.Keys)
            {
                // I CAN GET THE ATTACHMENT HERE
                string filename = fs.GetAsString(name).ToString();
                byte[] binary = iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader.GetStreamBytes((iTextSharp.text.pdf.PRStream)refs.GetAsStream(name));
            }
        }
    }
} 

/*
 * embedded level
 */
iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader reader = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader("samplepdf_embedded.pdf");
iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfDictionary root = reader.Catalog;
iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfDictionary documentnames = root.GetAsDict(iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfName.NAMES);
iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfDictionary embeddedfiles = documentnames.GetAsDict(iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfName.EMBEDDEDFILES);
iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfArray filespecs = embeddedfiles.GetAsArray(iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfName.NAMES);
for (int i = 0; i < filespecs.Size; ) {
    filespecs.GetAsString(i++);
    iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfDictionary filespec = filespecs.GetAsDict(i++);
    iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfDictionary refs = filespec.GetAsDict(iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfName.EF);
    foreach (iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfName key in refs.Keys)
    {
        iTextSharp.text.pdf.PRStream stream = (iTextSharp.text.pdf.PRStream)iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader.GetPdfObject(refs.GetAsIndirectObject(key));
        // I CAN GET THE ATTACHMENT HERE
        string filename = filespec.GetAsString(key).ToString();
        byte[] binary = iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader.GetStreamBytes(stream);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should provide some more information. E.g. how does your current code extract attachments? How do you sign and timestamp PDFs? Furthermore sample documents (both unsigned and signed) could help.

Comment: Post edited, I added my code and some sample pdf files. Thanks!

Comment: And what exactly happens? I assume a null access?

Answer (score 0):

I assume the issue is in your top code block which tries to find file attachment annotations. In its inner loop (which inspects each and every annotation) you have a construct:

```
if (iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfName.FILEATTACHMENT.Equals(annot.GetAsName(iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfName.SUBTYPE)))
{
    [...block 1...]
}
else
{
    [...block 2...]
}
```

Here block 1 and 2 are identical, i.e. you execute the code there in any case, both for annotations which *are* file attachments and for annotations which *are not*.

As long as the only annotations in your PDFs are file attachments, that does not matter, but as soon as there is one other annotation, the code in that block 2

```
iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfDictionary fs = annot.GetAsDict(iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfName.FS);
iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfDictionary refs = fs.GetAsDict(iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfName.EF);
foreach (iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfName name in refs.Keys)
{
    // I CAN GET THE ATTACHMENT HERE
    string filename = fs.GetAsString(name).ToString();
    byte[] binary = iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader.GetStreamBytes((iTextSharp.text.pdf.PRStream)refs.GetAsStream(name));
}
```

most likely blows up in your face because most other annotation types don't have a **/EF** entry, so `refs` is `null` and `refs.Keys` gives rise to an exception.

Unfortunately for you, integrated PDF signatures are form fields which (even if invisible) can be attached to some page as annotations. Thus, signing the PDF springs the trap in block 2.

The question arises why you try to extract attachments in Block 2 anyhow. According to the PDF specification, file attachment annotations must contain the type information the `if` looks for. Thus, no specification compliant PDF will make your code enter block 2 for file attachment annotations. Thus, you can simply remove that block 2.

Comment: You're right, block 2 is wrong (doing the same as block 1). Any idea how to get then the attachment while the PDF is signed? Can I reach them directly or should I remove the signature (clear form fields) first? If so, how can I do that with iTextSharp?

Comment: Why do you attempt to retrieve file attachments from annotations which are **not** file attachment annotations? Block 2 should do nothing. And if you think there may be annotations which are incorrectly labeled, you have to check each object you try to retrieve for `null`.